# Logic apps - having issues appending multiple text files to a text file blob

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have multiple text files; I need to append one to the other. I can't seem to get this to happen; maybe I am doing something wrong.

[image]

It’s not appending, its just returning the last text file

Answer (score 1):

I am able to append multiple text files to a text file blob by following the below workflow-

**Workflow**-

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Code**-

```json
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Create_blob_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": " ",
                    "headers": {
                        "ReadFileMetadataFromServer": true
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files",
                    "queries": {
                        "folderPath": "/demo",
                        "name": "FinalTextFile.txt",
                        "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Lists_blobs_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "contentTransfer": {
                        "transferMode": "Chunked"
                    }
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_string_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "FinalData",
                            "value": "@body('Get_blob_content_(V2)')"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Get_blob_content_(V2)": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "AppendToStringVariable"
                    },
                    "Get_blob_content_(V2)": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "get",
                            "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(items('For_each')?['Path']))}/content",
                            "queries": {
                                "inferContentType": true
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Lists_blobs_(V2)')?['value']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Create_blob_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "FinalData",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Lists_blobs_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/foldersV2/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('J=='))}",
                    "queries": {
                        "nextPageMarker": "",
                        "useFlatListing": false
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "J==": "/demo"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Update_blob_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": " @{variables('FinalData')}",
                    "headers": {
                        "ReadFileMetadataFromServer": true
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "put",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(body('Create_blob_(V2)')?['Path']))}"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {},
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureblob": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/********/resourceGroups/****/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/*********/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/azureblob"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**-

[image]

You can also use **Append to Array Variable** action.

Answer (score 0):

Set Variable will always overwrite the entire variable, so ending with the latest blob is expected behavior.

As already answered, use the **Append To** actions to get what you need. If you need to maintain the order of the text files, you can set the For each loop to run sequential by going to Settings -> Concurrency Control to Off -> Set Degree of Parallelism to 1

Comment: As you have pointed out, the solution is already covered in another answer. Consider upvoting the answer instead of adding a duplicate answer